# Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'

Tags: typescript

I am creating a simple function to remove duplicates from an array in typescript.

I know there are many different ways to achieve the goal, but my end goal is to learn how types work, so I don't need a solution that differs from my existing code.

## My Pseudo code:

- function will take in array of objects and key of object as parameters
- array of objects will be converted to a dictionary to only have unique entries
- construct the array from object and return it.

## Working code example using javascript:

```
function removeDuplicates(arr, propName) {
  const newArr = [];
  const lookup = {};

  for (let i in arr) {
    lookup[arr[i][propName]] = arr[i];
  }

  for (let i in lookup) {
    newArr.push(lookup[i]);
  }

  return newArr;
}
```

## Typescript code (throwing type error)

I am trying to convert that function to Typescript, but stuck at declaring types for lookup variable.

Here is my typescript code:

```
function removeDuplicates<T, K extends keyof T>(arr: T[], propName: K) {
  const newArr: T[] = [];
  const lookup: Partial<Record<T[K], T>> = {};
                               ^^^^ here is the error

  for (let i in arr) {
    lookup[arr[i][propName]] = arr[i];
  }

  for (let i in lookup) {
    newArr.push(lookup[i]);
  }

  return newArr;
}
```

## Error:

```
Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'
```

I know why I am getting the error. I am getting the error because value of object.key can be anything. But in my use case, I want to restrict the developer to pass in only the key whose value is either string | number. But I don't know how to do that in typescript.

Comment: You can take [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqEpjm); does that meet your needs?  If not, can you [edit] the question to demonstrate unmet use cases?  BTW there's another error in the code that you're not asking about; could you remove that so it doesn't distract from making this a [mre]?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the code in playground, I will fix the error and will update the question + will notify you once done

Comment: I have updated the code with working sample and is available here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYFs4DdUBEQAOANjBAIZSoDOAPACqKoAelYAJlYgEqoRzJsaAaQA0iAArI4BVMigBPIankA+MUMYtU7TgGtlcYIjoqAFGWTIAXMYDaAXTEEpBAHJl0qG0ICUiAN4AUIiIfGBUUIhEcHC6hIgAvIgWyAB0aGwgEKim5hAQYjCU6H4JKgHBIcn5tkUYts7S7p729omIdegA3JUhaFAgyEhk+T0hAL5i-uPJnDx8AvS2Qo7GKj49lf2DSADyAEYAVrxQqVhkRCDU9GbRsYQbgeNAA

Please add it as an answer, so I can accept it, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, you're getting the error because while `K` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be a key from the array element type `T`, there is nothing saying that the property at that key `T[K]` is itself key-like:

```
function removeDuplicates<T, K extends keyof T>(arr: T[], propName: K) {
    const lookup: Partial<Record<T[K], T>> = {}; // error!
}

removeDuplicatesOops([{ a: new Date(), b: "hey" }], "a"); // no error
```

In TypeScript, a type is "keylike" if it's assignable to `string | number | symbol`, which is [given a convenient alias](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/df673f74f5cf4fa1948ad2f8c25e6a0290d212ea/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L105) `PropertyKey`.

We can't constrain `T[K]` *directly*, but we can constrain `K` and/or `T` so that `T[K]` is effectively constrained. The easiest way to get your desired behavior where the compiler realizes that `Partial<Record<T[K], T>>` is an acceptable thing is to constrain `T` so that the property type at the keys in `K` must be assignable to `PropertyKey`:

```
function removeDuplicates<T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>, K extends keyof T>(
  arr: T[], propName: K) {
    const lookup: Partial<Record<T[K], T>> = {};
    // okay
}

removeDuplicates([{ a: new Date(), b: "hey" }], "a");
// ---------------> ~
// Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'PropertyKey'.
```

Yes, the constraints on `T` and `K` are circular, but in an allowable way (although it's sometimes tricky to avoid circularity warnings in situations like this).  Note that the error appears on the keys of the `arr` argument and not the `propName` argument itself.  If you really need the latter then you can constrain `K` even further like

```
function removeDuplicates<
    T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>,
    K extends keyof { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends PropertyKey ? P : never]: any }
>(arr: T[], propName: K) {
    const lookup: Partial<Record<T[K], T>> = {};
    // okay
}

removeDuplicates([{ a: new Date(), b: "hey" }], "a"); // error!
// -------------------------------------------> ~~~
//Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"b"'.
```

But this might be more complicated than you are looking for (and it would take me too far afield to explain how that `K` constraint works).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYFs4DdUBEQAOANjBAIZSoDOA8nAVQDwAqANIgNKKoAelYAEyqIA1qgCecYImYA+ABRlkyAFwyA2gF12BZPQByZdKjUcAlIgDeAKER3EEBFSiIicOCMJqACkthkiRgAlVEdkARZ1Dm0ZWVlEAF4rAF8Abmtk62s0TBx8YlIKajoGeXVLRDI1MFQAd0RcIvkzdgAjNQAiAAsJDsRkmI6yDrNUxAB6ccQwOG5lOGQs0EhYBBQMbDxCEnJKJmZuPlRBYRCwiI52bz0CVGQocQ4JWVZbey5efiFRCSlYxWUamYWh0N0MxlMFhs9gcThcbg8XkQvnuMACwVCCwiwOi7Dk8SSljSbzsk0QHjI4gyWRym3yOyKVDKFSq0zqDSaLUQ7UQ3V6-UGw1G1jJdz0yAAhDJxLdEAByRqUOWIGDCGYuMhUKgwADmYDIrSIqEQUFmD1lcuu9DuDye4jlADoluBoPAkLS8ttCnsALILVCMEkyQ5fU6Y8KMS7Im42x7PV4wj5HE4-STSCrqbwqpBiNPBzUabyaEPHb5W273OPiRAAfmRiGqqBwyE0ajIYGrmQUSlUGhiugMRhMnChQccYGcrncngIPj8aMCZyxkVxsQJKXSMLJFKpmWyG09BV21D9aGZlUb9UVqGabU6PXEfQG7CGIzGovmkpF4wAgsgdSAxhgC4fzmsacqvsqqrTHAGparq+qGsapqIAQShDpQyDktIYHyh0rQdI6QA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I would have given more points if allowed.