# SOLVED: How can I restrict a generic key using its values type?

Tags: typescript

This is not working because Item[Key] can be anything and I want to restrict key be either a string or a number. Errors are highlighted with ** and it says: `Type  does not satisfy the constraint string | number | symbol`

```js
function groupBy<
 Item, 
 Key extends keyof { [T in keyof Item]: Item[T] extends PropertyKey ? Item[T] : never}
>(items: Item[], key: Key): Record<**Item[Key]**, Item>{
 const groups = {} as Record<**Item[Key]**, Item>;
 for(const item of items){
   groups[item[key]] = {
     ...groups[item[key]],
     ...item
   };
 }
 return groups;
}
```

I also tried this but then i get this other error when I call the function, with the second parameter as 'name': `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'Record<"name", PropertyKey>'.`

```js
function groupBy<
  Item extends Record<Key, PropertyKey>,
  Key extends keyof Item
>(items: Item[], key: Key): Record<Item[Key], Item>{
  const groups = {} as Record<Item[Key], Item>;
  for(const item of items){
    groups[item[key]] = {
      ...groups[item[key]],
      ...item
    };
  }
  return groups;
}
```

Expected results:

```js
groupBy([
  {id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  {id: 1, age: 21 },
], 'isAlive'); //Should give me a type error


groupBy([
  {id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  {id: 1, age: 21 },
], 'id'); //Should work

groupBy([
  {id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  {id: 1, age: 21 },
], 'name'); //Should work

groupBy([
  {id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  {id: 1, age: 21 },
], 'age'); //Should work
```

Comment: it it expected that your `groupBy` function overrides whatever keys were already present? Shouldn't you be making groups as arrays?

Comment: @Murolem the functionality of it already works, and it's the expected result, I am just trying to fix the generic types

Comment: Your example isn't working partially because it's got at least one typo in it.  Please [edit] it to be a [mre].  Once you do that, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLAxeW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining or find a suitable duplicate target; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You are accepting optional fields, and your groupBy aggregates items without optional field under 'undefined' key. Is that intended? I tried [approach with accessor functions](https://tsplay.dev/mb184N) which is a bit easier to understand and is used for example by [RxJS groupby](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/groupby). @jcalz can you please write up an answer - I've never seen generic arguments referencing each other like in your solution

Comment: @Lesiak if this meets their needs then it will be like https://stackoverflow.com/a/76065071/2887218 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068491/2887218

Comment: @jcalz The problem of this solutions is that they are restricting having values that are not PropertyKeys on the object, and I want the restriction only on the second parameter (Key)

Comment: Hmm; [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLAxeW) from my first comment shows that non-key-like values like `false` are allowed. What specifically is the problem, can you demonstrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution combining multiple solutions on here:

```js
type KeysMatching<Item, Prop> = {
  [Key in keyof Item]-?: Item[Key] extends Prop ? Key : never
}[keyof Item]

function groupBy<
  Item extends Record<Key, PropertyKey>,
  Key extends KeysMatching<Item, PropertyKey>
>(items: Item[], key: Key): Record<Item[Key], Item>{
  const groups = {} as Record<Item[Key], Item>;
  for(const item of items){
    groups[item[key]] = {
      ...groups[item[key]],
      ...item
    };
  }
  return groups;
}

groupBy([
  {id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  {id: 1, age: 21, isAlive: true },
], 'isAlive'); //Should give me a type error


groupBy([
  {id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  {id: 1, age: 21 },
], 'id'); //Should work

groupBy([
  {id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  {id: 1, name: 'Marc',age: 21 },
], 'name'); //Should work

groupBy([
  {id: 1, age: 21,name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  {id: 1, age: 21 },
], 'age'); //Should work
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the main logic a little so that typescript will not complain as much — it seems to be behaving the same.

I couldn't get typescript to be happy about the `groupByValue` type when checking and assigning to accum, so I used `Record<any, any>` assertion on accum. I think it's okay to sometimes to do that, since typescript doesn't know it all and I'm not the smartest :)

See the comments in the code for details.

```
// what record key types are allowed
// note: record also supports Symbol keys. i've never used it, but it's there :)
type AllowedRecordKeyType = string | number;

// helper type to get the TRecord keys with values of type ValueType only
type RecordKeysWithValuesOfType<TRecord extends Record<any, unknown>, ValueType> = {
  [Key in keyof TRecord]: TRecord[Key] extends ValueType ? Key : never
}[keyof TRecord];

function groupBy<
  // constrain the item to be a record
  Item extends Record<any, unknown>,
  // get only the keys of Item values with the properties that are allowed to be a record key 
  Key extends RecordKeysWithValuesOfType<Item, AllowedRecordKeyType>,
  // typescript doesn't seem to be infering the correct type, 
  // so we help it to narrow it by intersecting with AllowedRecordKeyType
  TypeOfGroupByValue extends (Item[Key] & AllowedRecordKeyType)
>(items: Item[], key: Key): Record<TypeOfGroupByValue, Item[]> {
  return items.reduce((accum, item) => {
    const groupByValue = item[key] as TypeOfGroupByValue;

    if(groupByValue in accum)  {
      Object.assign((accum as Record<any, any>)[groupByValue], item);
    } else {
      (accum as Record<any, any>)[groupByValue as any] = { ...item }
    }
    
    return accum;
  }, { } as Record<TypeOfGroupByValue, Item[]>);
}

groupBy([
  { id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  { id: 1, age: 21 },
], 'isAlive'); //Should give me a type error


let r1 = groupBy([
  { id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  { id: 1, age: 21 },
], 'id'); //Should work


let r2 = groupBy([
  { id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  { id: 1, age: 21 },
], 'name'); //Should work

let r3 = groupBy([
  { id: 1, name: 'Marc', isAlive: false },
  { id: 1, age: 21 },
], 'age'); //Should work
```

Comment: Thank you for trying it, but I really want to know if there is any way to make it work perfectly, to make the function super simple to use and type safe.